# Retrieve Items in Video Document Library using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I'm wanting to retrieve all items within a Video Library on SharePoint and grab the owners/Created By list and all that I haven't been able to target videos only.

**I'm able to pull in all of the document libraries**:
[image]

**How do I pull items in only from the Video library?**
[image]

Here is what I currently have:

```
# Add SharePoint Snapin to PowerShell
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sourcevideo.f.com"
$Data = foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
        if ($list.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary”) {
            foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                foreach($version in $item.Versions){
                $data = @{
                        "Version" = $version.VersionLabel
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
                }
                New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
                }
            }
            $web.Dispose();
        }
    }
$Data  |  Export-Csv C:\Users\ptadmin\Desktop\process7.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are iterating all lists that has the base type "Document Library".

If you want to target a specific library you should use the method "Get-SPList" instead of the first for-loop.

```
$list = Get-SPList -ListName "Video" -Web $web
```

If you don't have the get-splist cmdlet use this

```
$list = $web.Lists["Video"]
```

**[Check if the file extension is .mp4]**

```
if($item.File.Name.EndsWith(".mp4"))
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks so much Fredrik! This worked like a charm, is there a way that I can grab only the .mp4's? It's currently grabbing all files even the thumbnails. I have this `if ($item.extension -eq "*mp4*"){` but it's not working well.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents, yes. You can find the file information on $item.File and to get the name, including the extension, you can use $item.File.Name. Use this to filter out the extensions with PowerShell.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents, added a row to my answer to check if the extension is ".mp4". Please mark as Answer if you are pleased. Cheers.